# Aspect advising other aspects

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I am currently developing two Spring applications that makes use of Spring-AOP. I have an aspect that allows simple performance logging which is defined as such:

```
@Aspect
final class PerformanceAdvice {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("perfLogger");

    public Object log(final ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("Logging statistics.");
    }
}
```

This advice can then be created through Spring AOP configuration with the following XML:

```
<bean id="performanceAdvice" class="com.acme.PerformanceAdvice" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="performanceAdvice">
        <aop:around pointcut="execution(* com.acme..*(..))" method="log"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

This works fine for classes that are created by Spring such as classes annotated with `@Service`. But I'd like this aspect to also advise **other aspects** in the secondary project. I'm aware Spring doesn't support this as noted in [their docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-at-aspectj):

> In Spring AOP, it is not possible to have aspects themselves be the target of advice from other aspects. The @Aspect annotation on a class marks it as an aspect, and hence excludes it from auto-proxying.

Thus I'm probably in need of something more powerful such as `AspectJ`. Or is it possible to make Spring aware of the aspect and still allow advising? From numerous other questions (that aren't directly related to this specific problem) on StackOverflow I have tried making aspects `@Configurable`, making them Spring-aware by defining them as a `@Component` and played around with various XML and plugin settings such as:

```
<context:spring-configured />
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:load-time-weaver/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

I'm running out of ideas now. Will I be needing to write fully-fledged `AspectJ` aspects? If so, can it use the same configuration such as Spring, referencing the existing aspect and defining a new pointcut? This would be useful so I don't have to re-work the `PerformanceAdvice` for `Project 1` but still reference and use it in `Project 2`.

**edit regarding [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030608/aspect-advising-other-aspects/36032589#comment59715114_36032397):**
To make myself more clear, I have the following example.

I have a Service in `Project 2`.

```
@Service
public class TargetSpringServiceImpl implements TargetSpringService {
    @Override
    public String doSomeComplexThings(String parameter) {
        return "Complex stuff";
    }
}
```

When this method gets called, I have an aspect that does some validation.

```
@Aspect
public class ValidationAdvice {
    @Autowired
    ValidationService validationService

    public void validate(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        //Calls the validationService to validate the parameters
    }
}
```

With the following pointcut as execution:

```
<bean id="validationAdvice" class="com.acme.advice.ValidationAdvice" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="validationAdvice">
        <aop:before pointcut="execution(* com.acme.service..*(..))" method="validate"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

I'd like to have my `PerformanceAdvice`'s `log()` method to be invoked on the `ValidationAdvice`'s `validate()` method. **NOT** on the `doSomeComplexThings()` method of the `TargetSpringService` class. As this is just an additional pointcut. The problem lies with advising the method of another aspect.

Comment: Why do you whant to advise an aspect ? you can just do the work in the aspect itself. Or you can create another aspect that advise the same method/class/etc as the first one

Comment: @JEY I'd like to advise another aspect to avoid code duplication. I COULD write the same performance logging logic in every other aspect I'd like to have some performance logging in, but it seems a lot neater to have an already existing aspect just do it for me instead of copy-pasting the logic.

Comment: what about inheritance ?

Comment: Don't you need the aspect to join multiple pointcuts? Is that what you need?

Comment: @JEY Well the `PerformanceAdvice` should not be a superclass of my other aspects, because the `PerformanceAdvice` should "do its magic" on the method of the aspect. e.g. instead of logging the `doIt()` method of the `RandomService` class, it should log the `doBefore()` method of `BeforeAspect` that's triggered when `doIt()` is called.

Comment: @fateddy In essence, yes. But Spring-AOP is not aware of the aspect since it's not created by the Spring container. This regards the Spring documentation quote that says _In Spring AOP, it is not possible to have aspects themselves be the target of advice from other aspects._

Comment: Are these two projects separate standalone projects (or does one depend on the other)?

Comment: @fateddy The project holding the `PerformanceAdvice` is a dependency of my secondary project. So in my secondary project, I can use the advice for service methods, but not for aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out two possible solutions to my problem. One is actually advising the aspect, the other works around the problem but is actually more elegant.

## Solution 1: Advise the aspect

In `AspectJ` it's possible to weave just about anything. With the help of a `META-INF/aop.xml` file as stated in the [AspectJ LTW documentation](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html), I could reference the aspect and define a new pointcut in the following way.

### Changes to project 1

#### The `PerformanceAdvice`

To allow `AspectJ` to define a new pointcut, the advice has to be `abstract` and have an abstract `pointcut` method that can be hooked into.

```
@Aspect
final class PerformanceAdvice extends AbstractPerformanceAdvice {
    @Override
    void externalPointcut(){}
}

@Aspect
public abstract class AbstractPerformanceAdvice {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("perfLogger");

    @Pointcut
    abstract void externalPointcut();

    @Around("externalPointcut()")
    public Object log(final ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("Logging statistics.");
    }
}
```

### Changes to project 2

#### The `META-INF/aop.xml`

The `aop.xml` file defines a new aspect called `ConcretePerformanceAdvice`. It extends of the `AbstractPerformanceAdvice` as well but defines a new pointcut. Then, in `AspectJ` it **IS** possible *(unlike in Spring-AOP)* to define a pointcut to another aspect.

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <concrete-aspect name="com.example.project2.ConcretePerformanceAdvice" extends="com.example.project1.AbstractPerformanceAdvice">
            <pointcut name="externalPointcut" expression="execution(* com.example.project2.ValidationAdvice.validate(..))"/>
        </concrete-aspect>
    </aspects>    
    <weaver options="-verbose"/>
</aspectj>
```

#### The `pom.xml`

Weaving the aspect requires some instrumentation. This requires both a dependency and a plugin to execute it. As for the dependency, it is the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

At the moment, during testing, I do the instrumentation through the `surefire-plugin`. That requires the following bit:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${org.springframework.version}/spring-instrument-${org.springframework.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

#### The Spring context

To enable the load-time weaving, it's also necessary to activate the weaving. So the following has to be added to the Spring context.

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

## Solution 2: Delegate to a Spring bean

`Spring-AOP` does not allow aspects to advise other aspects. But it does allow advice to be run on a Spring `@Component` of course. So the other solution would be to move the validation done in the advice, to another Spring bean. This Spring bean is then autowired into the advice and executed, but the `PerformanceAdvice` has its pointcut on the validation **component** and not on the validation **aspect**. So it would look like the following:

### Changes to project 1

None!

### Changes to project 2

The advice autowires the Spring `@Component` and delegates its logic to the component.

```
@Aspect
public class ValidationAdvice {
    @Autowired
    private ValidatorDefault validatorDefault;

    public void validate(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        validatorDefault.validate(jp);
    }
}

@Component
public class ValidatorDefault {
    @Autowired
    ValidationService validationService

    public void validate(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        //Calls the validationService to validate the parameters
    }
}
```

Then in the Spring context it's possible to define the pointcut on the `@Component` while the `ValidationAdvice` autowires the `@Component`.

```
<!-- Scan the package to find the ValidatorDefault component for autowiring -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.project2" />

<bean id="validationAdvice" class="com.example.project2.ValidationAdvice" />
<bean id="performanceAdvice" class="com.example.project1.PerformanceAdvice" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="validationAdvice">
        <aop:before pointcut="execution(* com.acme.service..*.*(..))" method="validate"/>
    </aop:aspect>
    <aop:aspect ref="performanceAdvice">
        <aop:around pointcut="execution(* com.example.project2.ValidatorDefault.validate(..))" method="log"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Spring does not use aspectJ to implement AOP but either JDK or cglib dynamic proxies. The aspectJ style here just refers to the syntax.

Aspectj aspects are static and use bytecode injection applied either at compile or at class-loading time.

Then spring is only able to apply proxy on objects it manages because dynamic proxies are applied during dependency injection. Moreover if you have 2 differents projects, you must ensure they share the same spring context or they will be isolated and applying aspect from 1 project to beans of the 2nd won't work.

And yes you will probably have to use real aspectJ aspects here. For performance logging purpose it's more suitable as there will be about no performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

So (from what I understand) you want to re-use the advise of your first project in your second project. But additionally you also want to add further logic to  the advise. This can be done by wrapping the advise of project-1 with a 
custom implementation in project-2.
You can do that with wrapping additional advices (see [Advice ordering](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering)):

**Project 1** requires some minor modifications (alternatively to implementing `Ordered` you could use the `@Order` annotation / and of course you could also inject the ordering instead of hardcoding it):

```
public class LoggingPerformanceAdvice implements org.springframework.core.Ordered {

    Object log(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
       // does the logging/statistics
       ...
       Object result = pjp.proceed(pjp.getArgs());
       ...
       return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
       return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

---

Create the custom Advice-advising implemenation in your **Project 2**

```
public class AdditionalPerformanceAdvice implements Ordered {

   Object log(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
      ...
      Object result = pjp.proceed(pjp.getArgs());
      ...
      return result;
   }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
       return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Wire the components together:

```
<!-- component of project 1 -->
<bean id="loggingPerformanceAdvice" class="com.acme.project1.LoggingPerformanceAdvice"/>
<!-- component of project 2 -->
<bean id="additionalPerformanceAdvice" class="com.acme.project2.AdditionalPerformanceAdvice"/>

<aop:config>
   <aop:aspect ref="loggingPerformanceAdvice">
      <aop:around pointcut="execution(* com.acme..*(..))" method="log"/>
   </aop:aspect>
   <aop:aspect ref="additionalPerformanceAdvice">
      <aop:around pointcut="execution(* com.acme..*(..))" method="log"/>
   </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Aspect with the `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` is called first.

Comment: I appreciate your extensive answer that introduces a nice implementation if I need an extension of the `PerformanceAdvice`. However, I'm afraid I didn't make myself clear enough. I do not wish to expand the functionality of the `PerformanceAdvice` logging. I'd like the `PerformanceAdvice`'s `log()` method to be executed **on** the method of another aspect. I will edit my question, but thank you for the effort of helping me.

Comment: Slightly modified the example - as the wrapping can be solved by ordering multiple advices. Read your question again - i dont understand what the difference would be to advise an aspect compared to wrapping a further aspect around your business methods...? If you could implement the behaviour using the decorator pattern - how would it look like?

Comment: In this concrete example, the difference is that I'd like to execute `log()` of `PerformanceAdvice` on `validate()` of `ValidationAdvice`. Assume the `log()` just checks how long the method took for completion, I'd like to know how long the `validate()` of `ValidationAdvice` took. Not how long the method in the service took. Ordering 2 aspects would just run both on the service's method. Which is not what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: So in the end you want to measure the execution of `ValidationService.validate` (which should be possible)? Using pure AspectJ to advise an aspect wouldnt solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you whant to perform action on aspect advices what i would do is something like that (Using aspectj can be change to spring annotation) :

```
public abstract aspect AspectPerformanceLogging {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AspectPerformanceLogging.class);

    before() : methodExecution() {
        LOG.info("Loggin stat");
        doBefore(thisJoinPoint);
        LOG.info("Loggin stat end");
    }

    after() : methodExecution() {
        LOG.info("Loggin stat");
        doAfter(thisJoinPoint);
        LOG.info("Loggin stat end");
    }

    Object around() : methodExecution() {
        LOG.info("Loggin stat");
        Object result = doAround((ProceedingJoinPoint)thisJoinPoint);
        LOG.info("Loggin stat end");
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract pointcut methodExecution();

    protected abstract Object doBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint);

    protected abstract Object doAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint);

    protected abstract Object doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint);
}
```

Then i create others aspects extending this aspect.